# current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block for postgresql with hibernate

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, transactions

I am using hibernate with postgresql dialect and I am running through a transaction error. This is my main app:

```
public class AppControl {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Configuration
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
    configuration.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
    Session session = null;
    Transaction transaction = null;

    //Session Factory
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();

    try {
        //Session
        session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        //Begin transaction
        transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        //DB operations

        Student student = new Student();
        student.setSno(2);
        student.setSname("Venky");
        session.save(student);
        session.flush();
        transaction.commit();
    }catch (RuntimeException e) {
        try {
            session.flush();
            transaction.rollback();
        }catch(Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Cannot rollback transaction");
        }
    } finally {

        session.close();
        sessionFactory.close();
    }

}
}
```

I encounter following error

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:54)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:190)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:62)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3124)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3581)
at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:103)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:461)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:347)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:350)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:56)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1222)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:425)
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101)
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:177)
at com.demo.app.AppControl.main(AppControl.java:32)
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2102)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1835)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:257)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:500)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:388)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeUpdate(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:334)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:187)
    ... 13 more
```

This is my student table:

sno(pk)|sname

Any help is appreciated. Thank You

Comment: have looked at this [example](https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-transaction-handle-example/)

Comment: I think there might be more to this stacktrace?

Comment: could this be caused by not setting `zip` and `course_no` for the student?

Comment: The first time I ran this program, it worked but it started giving this exception from second time.

Comment: then this is why https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17082652/hibernate-error-current-transaction-is-aborted-commands-ignored-until-end-of

Comment: *The first time I ran this program, it worked* so it probably has a unique key on `sno` so it is throwing an exception based upon that.  I feel that this relevant information is missing from your POST.  Good practices would dictate that you catch these exceptions

Comment: I removed zip and course_no from db. Even when I catch those exceptions and rollback transaction in catch, I am still facing the same issue

Comment: show your updated code.

Comment: updated the code

Answer (score 0):

A previous query failed, and you're presumably swallowing the exception somewhere so it's not output. Or you need to check back in the logs to find the *first* error.

Answer (score 0):

The schema defines the PK restriction. The `student.setSno(2)` is a primary key thus can't be duplicated. This is why the first run passed. You can try to change `2` to a different value or you can just delete the record from the PostgreSQL table and try to run the code again.

If you add the `System.out.printStackTrace(e)` to the catch block `}catch (RuntimeException e) {` I think you will see the source of the issue (e.g. the problem of inserting a new record with the same primary key).

The exception `Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block` says what it says - there was some failure in the currently running transaction and any commands done in the transaction will have no effect. You are expected to call `rollback` the transaction on the connection.

Comment: I did change the primary key on every run. I tried rolling back the transaction on connection but that didnt help either.

Comment: have you tried to print out the RuntimeException caught in the catch block if there is some more info what happened?